# Behavior of rest dsl with multiple http request and heavy processing

Tags: rest, spring-boot, apache-camel

Hello everyone i have a question.

I'm using **camel rest dsl** for exposing web service. This web serving push the message on an *activeMQ* broker, then a camel route do some process on and the http client receive the response.

[better undestanding with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Daj5V.png)

I simulate an heavy processing with the : delay(1000)

```
@**Component
public class TestRouteResponse extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    restConfiguration().contextPath("/rest-api").apiContextPath("/api-doc")
            .apiProperty("api.title", "Camel REST API").apiProperty("api.version", "1.0")
            .apiProperty("cors", "true").apiContextRouteId("doc-api").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

    rest("/test/{id}").get().description("Get ack nodejs.").route().inOut("activemq:inGenerale");

    from("activemq:inGenerale?concurrentConsumers=25").process(new Dumper()).delay(10000).setBody().constant("30")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200));
}
```

But when i'm calling the web service with URL localhost/test/id twice at the same moment, the first one will respond normallly after 10 seconds and the second one after 20 seconds.

i think the rest route is blocked while the first one is processing when the url are the same. But this behavior seems weird to me.

if i call the web service with url localhost/test/id and localhost/test/id2   twice again, no problem they respond both after 10 seconds.

Maybe there is something i dont understand with the behavior of camel rest dsl routing.

How can i perform a multiple call on the same rest endpoint with the same url  without waiting all the precedent call ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution.

We should use POST instead of GET in the rest DSL.

```
rest("/test/").post("/{id}").description("Get ack nodejs.").route().inOut("activemq:inGenerale");
```